# Force https on Hash fragmented url with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have website which developed by MVC js (EmberJS) so the all the routes is hash fragmented routes (eg. #/home), my problem now is that i am trying to force https with htaccess to all website but when i do that i always lose the fragmented part of the url.

How can i achieve that without losing the ash fragment part?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Ssl} !on
  RewriteRule (.*) https://example.dk [NE,L,R]
</IfModule>
```

Please help

Comment: Web server doesn't get part after `#`. It is all on client side only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following rule - which just testing now does not remove the hash;

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```